# HashCode on decimal with IEqualityComparer in a ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashcode, gethashcode, iequalitycomparer

I made a class to be used as a key in a dictionary.

```
public class FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo
{
    public uint IdOne { get; set; }
    public uint IdTwo { get; set; }
    public uint IdThree { get; set; }
    public uint IdFour { get; set; }
    public decimal DefinitionOne { get; set; }

    public class EqualityComparerAssetTableInfo : IEqualityComparer<FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo>
    {
        public bool Equals(FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo x, FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo y)
        {
            return x.IdOne == y.IdOne &&
                    x.IdTwo == y.IdTwo &&
                    x.IdThree == y.IdThree &&
                    x.IdFour == y.IdFour &&
                    x.DefinitionOne == y.DefinitionOne;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo x)
        {
            return (x.IdOne.ToString() +
                    x.IdTwo.ToString() +
                    x.IdThree.ToString() +
                    x.IdFour.ToString() +
                    x.DefinitionOne.ToString()).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo,uint> _derivativeIds = new ConcurrentDictionary<FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo, uint>(new FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo.EqualityComparerAssetTableInfo());
```

but when I try to lookup a value, based on the key like:

```
uint theID;
bool gotId = theDict.TryGetValue(keyInfoInfo, out theID);
```

it always returns false (even when I'm sure the value I want to find is actually there.
When I leave the public decimal DefinitionOne { get; set; } part out of the class and adjust the GetHashCode accordingly (like this)...

```
public class FourUintsKeyInfo
{
    public uint IdOne { get; set; }
    public uint IdTwo { get; set; }
    public uint IdThree { get; set; }
    public uint IdFour { get; set; }

    public class EqualityComparerAssetTableInfo : IEqualityComparer<FourUintsKeyInfo>
    {
        public bool Equals(FourUintsKeyInfo x, FourUintsKeyInfo y)
        {
            return  x.IdOne == y.IdOne && 
                    x.IdTwo == y.IdTwo && 
                    x.IdThree == y.IdThree && 
                    x.IdFour == y.IdFour;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(FourUintsKeyInfo x)
        {
            //todo: make a smarter / less cpu consuming algo
            return (x.IdOne.ToString() + x.IdTwo.ToString() + x.IdThree.ToString() + x.IdFour.ToString()).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

...it does work.

Any suggestions?

Kind regards,

Matthijs

**This does work:**

```
public int GetHashCode(FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo x)
        {
            //todo: make a smarter / less cpu consuming algo
            return (x.IdOne.ToString() +
                    x.IdTwo.ToString() +
                    x.IdThree.ToString() +
                    x.IdFour.ToString()).GetHashCode() +
                    x.DefinitionOne.GetHashCode();
        }
```

but it's probably not best practice...

**for Jon:**

strange thing...now it does work. Even with the old GetHasCode method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ShowError
```

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    ConcurrentDictionary<FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo,uint> _dictWithIds = new ConcurrentDictionary<FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo, uint>(new FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo.EqualityComparerFourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo());

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo theKey = new FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo() { IdOne = 1, IdTwo = 1, IdThree = 1, IdFour = 1, DefinitionOne = 15.25M };

        _dictWithIds.TryAdd(theKey, 1);

        uint theID;
        bool GotTheID = _dictWithIds.TryGetValue(theKey, out theID);

        GotTheID = GotTheID; //returns true :-S
    }
}


public class FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo
{
    public uint IdOne { get; set; }
    public uint IdTwo { get; set; }
    public uint IdThree { get; set; }
    public uint IdFour { get; set; }
    public decimal DefinitionOne { get; set; }

    public class EqualityComparerFourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo : IEqualityComparer<FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo>
    {
        public bool Equals(FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo x, FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo y)
        {
            return x.IdOne == y.IdOne &&
                    x.IdTwo == y.IdTwo &&
                    x.IdThree == y.IdThree &&
                    x.IdFour == y.IdFour &&
                    x.DefinitionOne == y.DefinitionOne;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo x)
        {
            //todo: make a smarter / less cpu consuming algo
            return (x.IdOne.ToString() +
                    x.IdTwo.ToString() +
                    x.IdThree.ToString() +
                    x.IdFour.ToString() +
                    x.DefinitionOne.ToString()).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Another extra edit: how it is filled.**

it seems to go wrong, when I fill the dictionary from database info (MySQL). I fill it like this:

```
if(reader != null)
                    {
                        while(reader.Read())
                            theDict.TryAdd(new FourUintsOneDecimalKeyInfo
                            {
                                IdOne = (uint)reader[0],
                                IdTwo = (uint)reader[1],
                                IdThree = (uint)reader[2],
                                IdFour = (uint)reader[3],
                                DefinitionOne = (decimal)reader[4]
                            }, (uint)reader[5]);

                        reader.Close();
                    }
```

Comment: Your key is currently mutable. That's a huge big warning sign. I would also strongly recommend *against* using ToString when coming up with a hash code - particularly for Decimal, where two numbers can be equal but have different string representations (e.g. 1.00m and 1.0m). Also, why have an equality comparer for the key rather than just making the key itself equatable?

Comment: Probably not related, but writing a `GetHashCode()` that uses mutable fields is a *Really Bad Idea*.

Comment: @JonSkeet "Also, why have an equality comparer for the key rather than just making the key itself equatable" you got a point there ;-)

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem. I can think of a few reasons this might be happening, but it's hard to tell without seeing it. I still think it should be an immutable type...

Comment: for some reason it now does work...

Comment: Please note my last edit:"Another extra edit: how it is filled.". Does this make sense why it doesn't work, when the dict is filled in this way?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Although `Decimal` returns `true` for `1.00m` and `1.0m`, that does not mean that such values are equivalent in all contexts.  Code which is interested in equivalence should regard those values as distinct.  Personally, I think `Equals` should mean equivalence (that's one of two meanings that could be defined for all class objects); to have some objects define it as something else severely weakens the Framework since it means there's no way for generic immutable objects to determine whether they are equivalent.